# Chrome character that is invisible but searchable

Tags: html, google-chrome, search, font-size

I work in a research project, and we have a python script that generates html texts that have a number of words highlighted. I would like to make the position of these highlighted words in the texts visible on the scroll bar. One way we could do this is by adding a special character (e.g. "$") after each of the marked words, and then run a search on this character.

We would like this character to be invisible, in order not to mess up the text visually.

I tried making a span class named "hidden", with font size 0. This does the job of hiding the $ sign, but Chrome search suddenly does not indicate the location on the scroll bar anymore. The search box still shows there are 57 results for "$", but the scroll bar highlights are gone, and clicking the "up" and "down" buttons does not bring me to the location of the next result.

I also tried inserting invisible commas (ampersandic;) in the text, but did not manage to search for these.

Other solutions, anyone?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `opacity: 0` which will visually hide the element but it will not remove the space of character.
To minimise the space you can decrease the font size to the minimum like `font-size: 1px`